# Apache 2 proxy for Tomcat 7

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy

Following the [how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html), I wanted to make a proxy for traffic to the address /app to be processed by Tomcat 7.

I added this to my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module  {path-to-modules}/mod_proxy.so    
LoadModule  deflate_module       modules/mod_deflate.so

ProxyPass         /app  http://localhost:8081
ProxyPassReverse  /app  http://localhost:8081
```

I also have this on my server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8081" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" 
              proxyName="localhost"
              proxyPort="80"/>
```

And I have the folder `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/app` with my application files.

I restarted both Tomcat 7 and Apache 2 after doing the configurations above.

**Problem:**
When navigating to my webpage.com/app, I get the error 500. I consulted apache logs, it says:

`[warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /app. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.`

**Update:**
This is running in ubuntu. 
I resolved this by adding `LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so` to my `httpd.conf`.

**Now I have another question:** How can I make this proxy to work on SSL through port 443?

Comment: Adding `LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so` to my `httpd.conf` resolved the issue.